# What script / function would allow me to subtract a value from a unique account

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, formulas

I have an item shop and bank account set up for my students in class using Sheets.  Currently students purchase their items via Google Forms and it logs their order in a Sheet.  Normally, I would find that student on the bank sheet and subtract from their account the total cost of their order, but I feel like there is a way that I can have google automate the process.

For example: Student1 spends $100.00 and then student27 spends $50.00

Is there a way for Sheets to find those unique individuals and then input a negative amount into their bank accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches. Here is one without a script. Say, the columns B and C are populated from the form, B has the name of a student, and C has the amount they paid. Then the query

```
=query("FormResponses!B:C", "select B, sum(C) group by B", 1)
```

will get the total amount spent by each student.

You can then subtract the query result from their bank balance. Say, the query output is in columns E:F of Sheet1. To get the amount spent by the student mentioned in some other cell H2, use

```
=iferror(vlookup(H2, E:F, 2, 0), 0)
```

which means: look for the name in H2 in the column E, and return the corresponding value from column F (2nd column of the searched range). If there is no match, 0 is returned as the student did not spend anything.